# Code Coverage using Scala Automation Testing for JS web application

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, javascript, coverage

I'm looking if there's an existing application or tool that will run code coverage based on a scala implemented automation suite running against a Javascript web application.

Our automation framework is using scala based on selenium.

If not, is this even possible or even a good way to utilize code coverage?